# Do I have to set most significant bits to zero if I shift right?

Tags: c++, bit-shift, bitmask

Let's say I have a 64-bit number and some bits that are set that hold a value, let's say three bits. I have a mask to get that value. To get the value of those three bits I bitwise 'AND' the number with the mask. This sets all other bits to zero. I then need to shift right towards the least significant bits so the least significant bit of the three-bit number is in the position of the least significant bit of the 64 bit number. After I shift right, do I need to mask again to ensure only all the bits to the left of those three bits are zero?

Comment: Depends on the language or the processor. In C and C++ you have unsigned longs, and in Java you have `>>>`, and in assembly you have LSR (logical shift right) or its equivalent on most processors. If you don't use one of these, yes you have to clear, as the shift will propagate everything including the sign bit downwards.

Comment: @user207421 I'm using C++. So if I use an unsigned type I don't need to clear it, it's safe to assume that right shifts will pad anything to the left with zeros, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: If the number is a `uint64_t`, there's no need to mask again; if its a `int64_t`, there would be the need for masking again, assuming the mask includes the most significant bit, but why not shift first and then apply the mask (`(x >> n) & 0b111`)?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, only tag one of them. Please remove [tag:c]

Comment: @phuclv In general as a matter of tagging policy you are correct: however they are identical in this respect.

Comment: @user207421: No, they are not identical in this respect. In C, the standard says right-shifts of negative values are implementation-defined. In C++, the standard says right-shifts of negative values are arithmetic shifts. (This is a recent change in the latest version of the standard.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do shift first then the mask and accomplish what you want:

```
int value = 0xdeadbeef;
value >>= 15;
value &= 0x7;
```

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In prior versions of the C++ standard, right-shifts of negative values were implementation-defined because signed integers could be one's-complement, two's-complement or sign+magnitude. So the behavior of right shift of a negative was implementation defined.

But all implementations of (modern) C++ are for CPUs using two's-complement and a lot of existing code relies on that implementation detail. In C++ 2020 this was finally acknowledged and signed integers are now defined as two's-complement.

The way shift right works depends on the type of the argument:

```
int value = -1;
value >>= 10;
```

Assuming two's-complement, which is now required, this will use an arithmetic shift and preserves the sign bit. So after the shift the value will still be -1 and have all bits set. If you mask before the shift then after the shift you get more bits then you bargained for.

```
unsigned int value = 0xFFFFFFFF;
value >>= 10;
```

This will use a logical shift and add zeroes to the left. So if you mask before the shift then you still get the right bits after the shift.

But why mask before the shift? If you mask after the shift then you always get the right bits regardless of the type.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to set most significant bits to zero if I shift right?
> After I shift right, do I need to mask again to ensure only all the bits to the left of those three bits are zero?

Yes, if the result of the mask was a signed type, a mask needed to cope with the sign bit shifted.

No if the result of the mask was a unsigned type.

```
uint64_t mask = ...;
uint64_t masked_value = mask & value;
uint64_t final = masked_value >> shift_amount;
```

---

If code did:

```
int64_t mask = 7 << shift_amount;
int64_t masked_value = mask & value;
int64_t almost_final = masked_value >> shift_amount; 
int final = (int) (masked_value & 7);
```

A smart compiler may emit efficient as as the *unsigned* approach above.